# Header, logic and database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I am having an issue with my header location. I am new to php and I am unable to redirect to my index page after this separate php file is run. In addition my function is unable to tell whether the contents of a text box is blank or equal to the default value of "<>".

Thank you

```
<?php
include('connectionFile.php');

//test for duplicate emails
$query="SELECT * FROM ClientEmail WHERE ClientEmailAddress = '$_POST[emailAdd]'";
$email=$_POST['emailAdd'];
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num==0)
  {
   if(isset($_POST['emailAdd']) && !empty($_POST['emailAdd']) &&        $_POST['emailAdd'].value != "<<please enter email>>")
{
// the form was submitted
//remove hacker HTML
$email2=strip_tags($_POST['emailAdd']);

//Insert data into database
$sql2="INSERT INTO ClientEmail SET ClientEmailAddress='$email2'";
$result=mysql_query($sql2);

//Direct back to homepage
echo "heloooo";
header('location:/index.php');
   }
else
{

header('location:/index.php');
}
}
else
{
header('Location:http://www.google.com');
`enter code here`}
?>
```

EDIT

After making the changes suggested my error log is as follows

Notice: Use of undefined constant db_selected - assumed 'db_selected' in /home/clubbtpk/public_html/connectionFile.php on line 15

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/clubbtpk/public_html/connectionFile.php:15) in /home/clubbtpk/public_html/addEmail.php on line 28

The code in the connection file is:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="username";
$password ="password";
// Create connection to mysql server
$con=mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password");

// Check connection
if (!$con)
  {
      die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
  }
  // Select database
  $db_selected = mysql_select_db("DB", $con);
  if(!db_selected)
  {
    die ("Cannot connect : " . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

EDIT 2

Resolved first error by changing
    if(!db_selected)
to
    if(!$db_selected)

RESOLVED
Added the following line of code to my index.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["emailAdd"])){
include("addEmail.php");
}
?>
```

Then changed the action of the form to "" so that it reloads the current page:

```
<form name="emailAddr" method="post" action="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not output anything before your redirect.

So this is not allowed:

```
echo "heloooo";
header('location:/index.php');
```

EDIT: You should definitely enable error_reporting on your script. I found another error in your query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ClientEmail WHERE ClientEmailAddress = '$_POST[emailAdd]'";
```

should be

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ClientEmail WHERE ClientEmailAddress = '" . $_POST['emailAdd'] . "'";
```

Furthermore you should not use the mysql_* functions anymore but upgrade to mysqli_* functions. And always check the inputted data before inserting them into sql-queries.

EDIT2: Add this at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

EDIT3:

You have to change this line too:

`if(isset($_POST['emailAdd']) && !empty($_POST['emailAdd']) && $_POST['emailAdd'].value != "<<please enter email>>")`

Should be:

`if(isset($_POST['emailAdd']) && $_POST['emailAdd'] != "<<please enter email>>")`

If you would turn error_reporting on you would see it yourself.

Comment: I used the echo to test the logic of the code. I took it out now and I just get a blank page

Comment: I added another section to my answer. You should add this code to the beginning of the script and paste error messages you receive in your question!

Comment: Even with the code I have I am able to add to the database. How exactly does your modified version change anything if I may ask? My main issue is still the redirect though

Comment: If you add the latest section of my answer to your code you will see the error messages. The redirect does not work because of the errors and your previous echo. So add the code and paste the errors you receive. Your first query will always return zero rows because of the wrong use of quotes.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant db_selected - assumed 'db_selected' in /home/clubbtpk/public_html/connectionFile.php on line 15

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in /home/clubbtpk/public_html/addEmail.php on line 16

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/clubbtpk/public_html/connectionFile.php:15) in /home/clubbtpk/public_html/addEmail.php on line 28

Comment: The second and third errors are fixed if you use the hints in my answer. For the first you should add the code of the connectionFile.php. Please add it to your question!